# The target type of this expression must be a functional interface in Java8

Tags: java-8

While trying to do this

```
int sum= (a, b) -> a + b;
```

getting below error:

> The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case that looks like a `BiFunction`:

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> fun = (a, b) -> a + b;
int sum = fun.apply(12, 13);
```

And the compiler sees `(a, b) -> a + b` as a lambda expression and that has to be assigned to some sort of a `Functional Interface`, but you are assigning it to an `int`.